# Не отображается ошибка текстбокса WPF интерфейса IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, интерфейс

Помогите пожалуйста

После запуска приложения текстбокс не выдает какой либо ошибки

Класс

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
  class Class1 : IDataErrorInfo
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
                    return "Name can't be empty.";
                    break;
            }

            return string.Empty;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="23" Margin="201,114,0,0" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="120"
        Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    
     />
</Grid>
```

Окно приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня ваш пример сразу показывает красную рамочку. А не забыли ли вы установить `DataContext`?

Comment: @VladD Не могли бы вы уточнить, где именно?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо! Действительно надо было в мэин форме указать контекст для класса, хотя в примере ничего про это не упоминалось.

Comment: Окей, тогда оформлю в ответ, для будущих поколений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код правильный.

Расследование в комментариях показало, что не хватает установки `DataContext`.